# Laravel 5.4 fetching image from wrong path

Tags: php, image, path, filesystems, laravel-5.4

I have a form that uploads data (including images) to my database and accessing that data from views. The problem is that laravel fetches the data from a wrong path. Kind of, anyway, this is why - the paths stored in the database read as;
**`http://localhost/var/www/html/theproject/public/img/uploads/img.jpg`**

which of course will be inaccessible because it should be;
**`http://localhost/theproject/public/img/uploads/img.jpg`**

This is the controller code that I used to set the location path to 'img/uploads';

```
$location = public_path('img/uploads');
$mydata->img1920 = $request->file('img1920')->move($location);
$mydata->save();
```

And accessed through a view like this

```
<img  src="{{ $mydata->img1920 }}" >
```

So why does laravel include **/var/www/html** in the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `public_path()` which will return the absolute path, not the path relative to your document root or public path (which you want).

When using `move()`, Laravel uses the given path relative to your public path:

So you can simple use:

```
$mydata->img1920 = $request->file('img1920')->move('img/uploads', $filename);
```

Where `$filename` is however you want to call the file.

---

You can also use `store()` or `storeAs()` combined with a configured filesystem, which works in the same way.

See: [Storing Uploaded Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The official docs say following about the helper function `public_path()`

> public_path()
>
> The public_path function returns the fully qualified path to the
>   public directory:
>
> $path = public_path();

`public_path` returns the FULLY qualified path.

Instead of `public_path()` try using `url()` or `move()`